# How do I setup Mandrill MX records and keep my old email?

Tags: email, mx-record, mandrill

I setup MX records for my domain.
According to the tutorial, all other records should be removed.
I removed the old records and have since realized that I still want a regular e-mail account,

```
   info@mydomain.com
```

How do I setup my MX records to handle this?

Mandrill's tutorial said that no other MX records are allowed.. I want to have info@mydomain route exist as well.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not possible to have a traditional inbox for a domain as well as have Mandrill accept email for that domain.  Instead, you'll likely want to have Mandrill handle only a subdomain, like inbound.domain.com, and set up the routes for that subdomain.  Your root domain could then be used for traditional inboxes for sending and receiving mail.

Alternately, you can set up your root domain to be handled by Mandrill. Whenever you get mail to info@yourdomain.com, you'd process the webhook POST, and use the information from that POST to create a new outbound message to some other inbox where you can receive mail.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but could you please share a link on how to setup subdomain with Mandrill and also webhook POST.